# Поиск в массиве с возможностью изменения результата

Tags: php

Требуется написать функцию, через которую можно будет в массиве найти элемент, и при необходимости изменить найденный элемент.

Массив такого вида:

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Tra-ta-ta",
        "id" => 213
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Test name",
        "id" => 25
    ),
    ...
);
```

Для решения задачи написал такую функцию:

```
function &arraySearchByField(
        array &$array, string $fieldName, string $haystack): ?array
    {
        foreach($array as $key => &$arItem)
            if($arItem[$fieldName] == $haystack)
                return $arItem;
        return null;
    }
```

И использую таким образом:

```
if($searchValue = &arraySearchByField($myArray, "name", "Test name")) {
    $searchValue["id] = 123;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли для решения этой задачи реализовал работу со ссылками ? Могут ли быть какие-то непредвиденные ошибки при возвращении ссылки подобным образом ?

Comment: Всё правильно, единственное что вызывает опасения - это return null, т.к. в этом случае вы не возвращаете ссылочное значение, и выбрасывается notice. Обычно для работы с массивами в PHP используются другие механизмы, но раз вы работаете с сылками то вам это не актуально.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov спасибо! А как можно обойти notice ?

правильно понимаю, что можно просто объявить переменную $null = null; и возвращать переменную ?

Comment: Но как-то костыльно выглядит..

Comment: Можете добавить $empty = []; и возвращать её же вместо null внутри функции. Да, это костыльно, но опять же потому что в PHP другие механизмы для работы с массивами, ссылки же в нём не развиты в такой же степени как, скажем, в C/C++. Ссылка в массиве PHP - это ключ значения, индекс, а не непосредственно сама ссылка через оператор.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov понял, спасибо! я как раз после C++))
О каких механизмах php идет речь для работы с массивами ?

Задача заключается в том, чтобы по какому-то полю массива, найти элемент и изменить его другие поля.

Comment: array_search не подходит, т.к. ищет только в одномерном массиве.

Comment: И думаю, как вариант можно не ссылку возвращать а ключ (как это делает `array_search `), а уже по ключу изменить элемент.

Comment: Перенесено в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96809/q-1008304), присоединяйтесь

Comment: @DanielProtopopov к сожалению репутации не хватает(

Comment: В вашем случае вам нужно иметь задачу, и соответственно под неё искать решение. Если ваше задание - это то, как работают ссылки в PHP, то оно достигнуто. Если задача заключается в том, как это лучше сделать в PHP, то она еще впереди.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov у меня нет задачи сделать это через ссылки. Я сделал так, как знал. А о каких методах решения этой задачи (поиска и изменения элемента массива) идет речь ?

Comment: Для этого рекомендую создать новый вопрос (без привязки к ссылкам) после изучения уже существующих вопросов (и ответов к ним) в нашем сообществе, либо изучением [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov честно говоря с 95% этих функций знаком, и с php работаю более 6 лет, и даже представить не могу, какой может быть функционал для решения. Очень интересно.

доп. вопрос задал.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть лучше искать ключ?

```
function getItemKey($list, $name, $value) {
  foreach ($list as $key => $item) {
    if ($item[$name] == $value) {
      return $key;
    }
  }
}
```

Пример использования

```
if ($key = getItemKey($myArray, 'name', 'Test name')) {
  $item = $myArray[$key];
  if (someCondition()) {
    $item['id'] = '123';
    $myArray[$key] = $item;
    // или
    $myArray[$key]['id'] = '123';
  }
}
```